# Text-to-audio iOS app for iPhone

Tags: ios, audio, iphone-app, speech-synthesis

I use [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/), and I click the "Read Later" bookmarklet all the time. Unfortunately, I don't have time to read all the articles that I save for later, and I can't possibly read them while I'm walking to work. But I can listen to them... if only there was an app.

Is there any native app, extension, or mobile web app that can turn my saved articles into audio so I can read them on the go?

Comment: Please indicate price range. There are some very good, but very expensive solutions to this that are aimed at the visually impaired (totally or fully bind persons).

Answer (score 2):

As of Sep 2014's iOS 8 update, [Instapaper offers text-to-speech](http://blog.instapaper.com/post/97750859246).

Text-to-Speech playlists on mobile are available to premium members.

Answer (score 1):

[audiotext.ws text to speech](http://audiotext.ws) is not an app but you can use the website from your phone to convert your English texts to audio. Play the generated audio online or save an mp3 file for later use while you are on the road.

Comment: This looks interesting. Unfortunately it has a fairly short word limit (5000 words), and it's currently taking 10 minutes to convert to audio. (I'm still waiting.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) app takes advantage of Android text-to-speech engine.
You may switch to this app, as its functionality is quite similar to instapaper's, or simply share the article from instapaper to pocket and then "play" the article.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has introduced text to speech capabilities in iOS 7 and made several refinements since then, most notably in iOS 16 where it has added a new Premium tier of voices available for free download.

You can use them with system provided tools like Spoken Content, and if you need there are multiple apps, my app Speech Central allows you to read one book a month completely free.